# How to calculate current sink

Tags: current, bias, lm317

Below schematic is what I have on the breadboard:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyieCU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 is there to sink 10mA of current to bias LM317, but 470 ohm is a value that I achieved by trial and error!

What's the equation for this circuit to calculate how much current is being "sink" by the NPN transistor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2N3904 base is at 0 volts and the emitter resistor connects to -5 volts. Given that the base emitter junction can be approximated to a 0.7 volt drop, the voltage across the emitter resistor is about 4.3 volts. This means that a 470 ohm resistor will have about 9.15 mA flowing through it.

Comment: Thanks, can I please ask your opinion about this circuit in general? downsides, ways to improve... etc.

Comment: It seems OK (nothing special performance wise) but, if you were after better performance (in some respect) or less heat generated by the LM317 then you need to state what your design aims are.

Comment: Trying to build a lab PSU 0-20V / 1A - 1mV/A per step, I did put an switching regulator before LM317 as a pre-regolator with two LC filter on it's output. the output of switching regulator is always 3V higher than adjust pin but I don't have an oscilloscope to see if there's any ripple at the output or it's oscillating or not. The ultimate goal is to have a digitally controlled PSU. the voltage part is almost done, after this going to try to design the current control part.

Comment: OK, that'll run nice and cool then. Good luck.

Comment: The joy of being approved by a pro. thanks.